In R, how do you pull a coefficient value from the summary function?
How do you pull out a coefficient value from the summary of a linear regression model?
The first two are obtainable with lm1$coefficients[1] or [2], but I'm not sure how to get the third value. In the sprintf code below, I get NA if I use lm1$coefficients[3] or incorrect number of dimensions if lm1$coefficients[1:2,1] is used. In the summary example, the two values I'd want to substitute for %s are 295.274 and 62.012. Does anyone know how to access the latter?
sprintf("The linear relationship can be described using the fitted regression line: Household debt = %s + %s", lm1$coefficients[1], lm1$coefficients[0,1])

> str(summary(M.lm))  # Truncated output...
List of 11
 $ call         : language lm(formula = MaxSalary ~ Score, data = salarygov)
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 MaxSalary ~ Score
 ...
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:495] -232.3 -132.6 37.9 114.3 232.3 ...
 $ coefficients : num [1:2, 1:4] 295.274 5.76 62.012 0.123 4.762 ...
 $ aliased      : Named logi [1:2] FALSE FALSE
 $ sigma        : num 507
 $ df           : int [1:3] 2 493 2
 $ r.squared    : num 0.817
 $ adj.r.squared: num 0.816
 $ fstatistic   : Named num [1:3] 2194 1 493
 $ cov.unscaled : num [1:2, 1:2] 1.50e-02 -2.76e-05 -2.76e-05 5.88e-08


Generally it's easier to pull it straight from the model object, coef(M.lm)

1) lm Suppose
fm <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars) # mtcars comes with R

then coef(fm) is the coefficient vector so coef(fm)[i] is the ith coefficient.  Use coef(fm)[[i]] if you don't want the name.
Example With lm output
fm <- lm(mpg ~., mtcars)
fm
##
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp         drat           wt  
##    12.30337     -0.11144      0.01334     -0.02148      0.78711     -3.71530  
##        qsec           vs           am         gear         carb  
##     0.82104      0.31776      2.52023      0.65541     -0.19942  

coef(fm)[3]
##       disp 
## 0.01333524 

coef(fm)[[3]]
## [1] 0.01333524

2) summary It is easier to use the output from lm than the output of summary but if for some reason you want to use the output of summary rather than output of lm
s <- summary(fm)

then coef(s)[, 1] is the coefficient vector so coef(s)[i, 1] is the ith coefficient. We can alternately use coef(s)[i, "Estimate"] since coef(s) produces a matrix with row and column names.
Same example with summary output:
s <- summary(fm)
s
##
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
##
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -3.4506 -1.6044 -0.1196  1.2193  4.6271 
##
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
## (Intercept) 12.30337   18.71788   0.657   0.5181  
## cyl         -0.11144    1.04502  -0.107   0.9161  
## disp         0.01334    0.01786   0.747   0.4635  
## hp          -0.02148    0.02177  -0.987   0.3350  
## ...snip...

coef(s)[3, 1]
## [1] 0.01333524

coef(s)[3, "Estimate"]
## [1] 0.01333524

3) broom Another possibility is to use the broom package.  In that case it works the same with both fm and s.
library(broom)

tidy(fm)$estimate[3]
## [1] 0.01333524

tidy(s)$estimate[3]
## [1] 0.01333524

4) collapse flm from the collapse package directly produces coefficients:
library(collapse)

co <- flm(mpg ~., mtcars)
co[3]
## [1] 0.01333524

